# visual studio team services build issue

Tags: tfs, build

I'm testing the build feature within visual studio team services. I created and mapped a Hello world ASP MVC solution to my vstsc.

But then when I'm trying to build it I run into a weird error at the build solution level. It tells me it couldn't resolve the assembly references. When I try this within my local visual studio it builds correctly.

Here is a couple of lines from the build output

> Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(82,27): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Controllers\ManageController.cs(82,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\Main\AppTest\AppTest\AppTest.csproj]
>   Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(104,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Controllers\ManageController.cs(104,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\Main\AppTest\AppTest\AppTest.csproj]
>   Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(111,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Controllers\ManageController.cs(111,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\Main\AppTest\AppTest\AppTest.csproj]
>   Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(111,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Controllers\ManageController.cs(111,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\Main\AppTest\AppTest\AppTest.csproj]
>   Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(112,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Controllers\ManageController.cs(112,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\Main\AppTest\AppTest\AppTest.csproj]
>   Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(112,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryToken' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Controllers\ManageController.cs(112,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryToken' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\Main\AppTest\AppTest\AppTest.csproj]
>   Main\AppTest\AppTest\Controllers\ManageController.cs(113,27): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added a nuget restore task as part of your build steps?

Comment: Which build definition template do you choose? Or which build tasks do you add in your build definition? How do you add assembly references on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using Nuget to restore the package needed.
2. Try to use default `Visual Studio` build definition template or add a `Nuget Installer` step before build step:

[image]